# How to include survey weights into a random intercept model?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model, survey-weights

I'm trying to run a random intercept model in R on an adolescent dataset with >100 schools (the school being the intercept).

The data include a survey weight value for each observation, however lme and lmer seem to only take frequency weights, not survey weights.

Anyone know how to incorporate survey weights with lme or lmer?